# bigfoot: only break footnotes across double-page spread

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, double-sided, widows-orphans, bigfoot

The `bigfoot` handles the breaking of footnotes across pages quite well, but personally I don't like it if I have to turn the page to read a complete footnote.

Therefore my question: Is it possible to make `bigfoot` only break footnotes if the its second part will be on the opposite side of a double-page spread?

Another footnote-related question: There doesn't seem to be widow control when it comes to footnotes. I occasionally have broken footnotes where there are only a few words on the new side. This looks, of course, quite ugly – can this be avoided?

Comment: I don't have time to test it right now but, regarding your first question, how about trying to use the `chngpage` package (unless you are using `memoir`, which implements it) to test whether the page is odd or even, and then something like `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000` (not sure how it interacts with `bigfoot`).

Answer (score 8):

I think `bigfoot` has (undocumented) `\footnotewidowpenalty` and `\footnoteclubpenalty` values.

Comment: Would you care to add some more detail in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates its usage (since these counters are undocumented)?

Comment: setting both `\footnotewidowpenalty` and `\footnoteclubpenalty` to 10000 does indeed prevent single lines in broken footnotes. So this does take care of the second part of my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Taking ienissei's hint I tried to do this with `komascript`s `\ifthispageodd` command and encountered something interesting: As my MWE shows this doesn't produce stable results – each time I typeset the MWE the footnotes are broken differently:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=8000
\newcommand*{\smartfootnote}[1]{\ifthispageodd{\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000}{\interfootnotelinepenalty=8000}\footnote{#1}\interfootnotelinepenalty=9000}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext\smartfootnote{\blindtext}

\blindtext\smartfootnote{\blindtext}

\blindtext

\blindtext\smartfootnote{\blindtext\blindtext} \blindtext

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\smartfootnote{\blindtext} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

After the first run footnote 3 is broken across pages 2 and 3 as it should be, while footnote 4 is unbroken on page 4. After the second run, footnote 4 is broken across pages 3 and 4 which is wrong, after the third run, we're again correct. And so on and so on …

While I understand why this is happening, this is definitely not the last word on this.

Comment: I had tried to implement something similar with `memoir` and never reached a satisfactory result either. Hopefully someone will find.